# Unified textfields CSS/Bootstrap only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I was hoping someone could help me with this. I am trying to create this example: 
[image]

These are (three) text boxes. Example:

[image]

I tried putting text box in side a div and making it's width pretty low and aligning a second text box next to it. I set border: none and then 
border-right: solid black 1px but on bootstrap I end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: I would think you'd want to eliminate all borders of your text boxes, and then put them in a div with a full border.

Comment: Yes, that is what I initial tried. Remove all borders and set the right side border for the small text box.

Comment: That's not what I said. **No** border for the text boxes. **Full** borders for the div.

Comment: I need the line between the first and second text box, any suggestion on that?

Comment: Maybe an inner div, of even a graphic image. It may work for you. I just think you might have trouble showing only some borders of a text box.

Comment: @JonathanWood Thanks, I used your first suggestion and worked great. I had to override Bootstrap's CSS using !important though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer to my own question, may be useful to some one else in the future.

Iv used the following HTML:

```
<div class="addressMain">
    <div class="addressBorder">
        <div class="addressUnified">
            <input type="text" placeholder="No." class="small" ></input>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address Details..." class="med"></input>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="big"></input>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="big"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.addressUnified .med{
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
    border-left: solid grey 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    outline: none
}

.addressUnified .big{
    width: 100%;
    border:none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    outline: none
}

.addressUnified .small{
    width:10%;
    border:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    outline: none
}

.addressUnified{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    border: solid grey 1px;
}
```

The results were exactly as I wanted in the original question. Thanks John for your help!

note, override any bootstrap css using !important.